# How do I automate SAP GUI with c#

Tags: c#, sap-gui

I would like to automate an SAP GUI window using the C# language. I am able to do it in VBScript but code reuse is horrible. Besides Id like to use threading instead of having 80 or more processes running. Where can I find any documentation and samples of how to do this? Here is the code I am working with. Basically, the problem I am facing is - how do I make a connection to SAP GUI then create an SAP GUI on the fly then start making transactions and entering text in some fields.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using White.Core.Factory;
using White.Core.UIItems.Finders;
using White.Core.InputDevices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using SAP.Connector;
using SAP;


namespace SAP_Automation
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ExeSourceFile = @"C:\Program Files\SAP\SapSetup\setup\SAL\SapLogon.s8l";
            White.Core.Application _application;
            White.Core.UIItems.WindowItems.Window _mainWindow;

            var c = SAP.Connector.Connection.GetConnection("**");
            var c = new SAPConnection("ASHOST=*; GWHOST=*; GWSERV=*; ASHOST=*; SYSNR=00;USER=user; PASSWD=**;");
            c.Open();


            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I can create a connection but I dont know how to create a session to the GUI and start entering text in fields. Any examples and samples would be appreciated.

Comment: I have had excellent luck in converting VBScript code for a 3rd Party program that communicates through the COM at work.  For the most part I've been able to do a straight conversion from one to the other when factoring out the language differences.  Have you attempted this yet?

Comment: Yes, we have a lot of VBScript code that automates SAP. But, we cannot establish a connection to the SAPGUI. This VB code is not translatable to c#. There is no where on the internet that gives an example of this. @Hans - yes scripting is enabled and we are able to automate some parts but we are unable to automate launching an SAP window in C#.

Comment: It seems that the SAP .NET client has RFC and SOAP support, would that help or are you forced to work in GUI?

Comment: I just tried that and its working like a charm...
but after the sap form fired and got directly into the transaction if the user wants to close the sap form he cant...unless he will close my winforms application. Is there a way to open sap transaction window from winforms application and close it without closing the whole application

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This might be necro-threading but I was in a similar situation where I work. We needed SAP GUI Automation for testing purposes that could integrate with the rest of our homegrown automation platform written in C#. I helped create a proposal for one solution that took advantage of a SAP provided library for GUI automation that could be used as the basis for an automation layer for SAP.

Does the following file exist on your SAP file installation? x:\Program Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPGui\sapfewse.ocx?

If so, add it to Visual Studio (or whatever IDE you're using) as a reference. It is basically a class library which contains a bunch of SAP specific objects that will allow you to interact with. It is very effective because it exposes most of what you need from the SAP GUI. We discovered in other attempts that a lot of the objects in SAP were not available.

This is an early proof of concept I did. Start SAP with a connection string, enter credentials, navigate to a transaction code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SAPFEWSELib;

namespace SAPGuiAutomated
{
//created a class for the SAP app, connection, and session objects as well as for common methods. 
    public class SAPActive
    {
        public static GuiApplication SapGuiApp { get; set; }
        public static GuiConnection SapConnection { get; set; }
        public static GuiSession SapSession { get; set; }

        public static void openSap(string env)
        {
            SAPActive.SapGuiApp = new GuiApplication();

            string connectString = null;
            if (env.ToUpper().Equals("DEFAULT"))
            {
                connectString = "1.0 Test ERP (DEFAULT)";
            }
            else
            {
                connectString = env;
            }
            SAPActive.SapConnection = SAPActive.SapGuiApp.OpenConnection(connectString, Sync: true); //creates connection
            SAPActive.SapSession = (GuiSession)SAPActive.SapConnection.Sessions.Item(0); //creates the Gui session off the connection you made
        }

        public void login(string myclient, string mylogin, string mypass, string mylang)
        {
            GuiTextField client  = (GuiTextField)SAPActive.SapSession.ActiveWindow.FindByName("RSYST-MANDT", "GuiTextField");
            GuiTextField login  = (GuiTextField)SAPActive.SapSession.ActiveWindow.FindByName("RSYST-BNAME", "GuiTextField");
            GuiTextField pass  = (GuiTextField)SAPActive.SapSession.ActiveWindow.FindByName("RSYST-BCODE", "GuiPasswordField");
            GuiTextField language  = (GuiTextField)SAPActive.SapSession.ActiveWindow.FindByName("RSYST-LANGU", "GuiTextField");

            client.SetFocus();
            client.text = myclient;
            login.SetFocus();
            login.Text = mylogin;
            pass.SetFocus();
            pass.Text = mypass;
            language.SetFocus();
            language.Text = mylang; 

            //Press the green checkmark button which is about the same as the enter key 
            GuiButton btn = (GuiButton)SapSession.FindById("/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]");
            btn.SetFocus(); 
            btn.Press();

        }
    }
    //--------------------------//
    //main method somewhere else 
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SAPActive.openSAP("my connection string");
        SAPActive.login("10", "jdoe", "password", "EN");
        SAPActive.SapSession.StartTransaction("VA03");
    }
```

You're right there is not a lot of documentation on this subject. Below are a few sources that helped me get started

-Original source of our plan
http://scn.sap.com/thread/1729689

-Documentation on the API (For VB and javascript but the general rules and objects are identical). Definitely read the portion on the SAP GUI Runtime hierarchy. It'll answer a lot of questions. 
http://www.synactive.com/download/sap%20gui%20scripting/sap%20gui%20scripting%20api.pdf

Comment: OMG..thank you soo much for this. If I wasnt so poor I would pay you.

Comment: your code has also helped me. I have tried your example exactly as you describe it, but when I run it, i get the following message : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {B90F32AD-859E-4EDD-BFAE-C9216849520C} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
Which is the Class which is not registered? Can you give ideas how to overcome this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From a quick google of that error a lot of people say it is a x86 vs x64 problem. Not completely sure to be honest. Try searching around a bit or starting a new thread. I don't have an answer for you as I have never ran into that error myself.

Comment: I normally dont like to revive old post but there is such little documentation on this so I figured it might be good to do so.  When I do a SapGuiApp.OpenConnection or OpenConnectionByConnectionString my Sessions property off that object always has a count of 0 which in turn causes the next line to fail where you set the session to the first index of Sessions Collection.  My code to that point is verbatim could it be my connection string is causing the issue I have swapped info for my connection properties.  I am not having much luck with this.

Comment: @Bearcat9425 It should be a connection string problem. I do not remember exactly, but inside the SAP 720 Launch pad options/preferences there is a place which shows the connection string you should be using.

Comment: @TYH Thanks for the Reply!!! It was really weird because I was actually connecting to SAP and logging in using the SSO connection string but once I was connected it was like that session was null.  Come to find out there is a setting in SAP that SAP GUI Scripting must be turned on before you can obtain that session.  However it is a huge security so right now our abap developer is converting the transaction we needed to run into a Remote Enabled BAPI.  Then we can use the .net connector 3.0 to call it.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Bearcat9425 Glad to hear you solved the problem and that you have support from your SAP team to use the .NET Connector over this GUI stuff.

Comment: Is there any way to capture "Tab" click using GuiSession.change handler or any other event. also i'm looking for alternative to SAPFEWSELib for SAP automation

Answer (score 1):

It is very important here to understand what UI Automation can do and what its limitations are.  It was designed to automate a user interface's capabilities.  You can click buttons, enter text in a textbox, move windows, etcetera, whatever a user can do using the mouse and keyboard.

What it can **not** do is bridge the tall wall that the operating system puts up between processes.  A wall that prevents a process from accessing the memory of another process.  This is a very important security and safety feature.  It for one prevents a process from accessing data that should be private to a process.  Like a password.  And for another it stops a crashing process from affecting other processes that run on the machine.  You can kill a process with Task Manager and everything keeps motoring along happily as though nothing happened.

A consequence of this is that creating a SAPConnection object in your program is a connection that only your program can use.  There is no mechanism to somehow pass this object to another process with UI Automation.  At best you could use the data you retrieve from the connection to affect what buttons you click.

The kind of process interop that would allow sharing data between processes is well supported in .NET.  Low-level approaches are socket and named pipes, high-level are Remoting and WCF.  Older programs have COM Automation support, Office is a good example of that.  That however requires two to tango, both programs must be written to take advantage of it.

So if you are trying to automate an existing SAP application and this app does not otherwise explicitly support automation, the kind that an Office program supports, then you are pretty much stuck with just filling text boxes and clicking buttons.

Answer (score -2):

You can automate any kind of application (browser, desktop, java, etc) with [UiPath](http://uipath.com). 
Here's a [tutorial on how to automate data entry, menu navigation and screen scraping on SAP.](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/sap-gui-automation-data-entry)

You can

- use it from code (SDK). It has a tool that auto-generates C# code
- create and run workflows (visual automation) directly from [UiPath Studio](http://www.uipath.com/desktop-automation).

Here's a sample of the C# auto-generated code:

```
        // Attach window  menu
        UiNode wnd3 = UiFactory.Instance.NewUiNode().FromSelector("<wnd app='sap business one.exe' cls='&#35;32768' idx='1' />");            
        // Click 'Business Pa...' menu
        UiNode uiClickBusinessPamenu_3 = wnd3.FindFirst(UiFindScope.UI_FIND_DESCENDANTS, "<ctrl name='Business Partners' role='popup menu' /><ctrl automationid='2561' />");
        uiClickBusinessPamenu_3.Click(88, 9, UiClickType.UI_CLICK_SINGLE, UiMouseButton.UI_BTN_LEFT, UiInputMethod.UI_HARDWARE_EVENTS);            
        // Attach window 'SAP Business' 
        UiNode wnd4 = UiFactory.Instance.NewUiNode().FromSelector("<wnd app='sap business one.exe' cls='TMFrameClass' title='SAP Business One 9.0 - OEC Computers' />");            
        // Click 'Add' button
        UiNode uiClickAddbutton_4 = wnd4.FindFirst(UiFindScope.UI_FIND_DESCENDANTS, "<wnd cls='ToolbarWindow32' title='View' /><ctrl name='View' role='tool bar' /><ctrl name='Add' role='push button' />");
        uiClickAddbutton_4.Click(13, 24, UiClickType.UI_CLICK_SINGLE, UiMouseButton.UI_BTN_LEFT, UiInputMethod.UI_HARDWARE_EVENTS);
```

Here's how workflow automation of SAP Business One menus, buttons or typing looks like:

[image]

And finally the SDK documentation is located [here](https://github.com/uipath/sdk/wiki)... in case you don't want to use workflows.

**Note:** I work at UiPath. You should also try other automation tools like Automation Anywhere, WinAutomation, Jacada, Selenium, Ranorex use them side by side and choose the one that suits better your needs.