# How do I find my Connection String required to automate SAP GUI through a C# application?

Tags: c#, automation, connection-string, sap-gui

I am trying to make a connection to SAP GUI through C#. For reference, I am using code found here: [How do I automate SAP GUI with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130176/how-do-i-automate-sap-gui-with-c-sharp)

I have added a reference to sapfewse.ocx and the corresponding using statement. Here is my code:

```
using SAPFEWSELib;

private void OpenSAP()
{
    GuiApplication Application;
    GuiConnection Connection;
    GuiSession Session;
                        
    Application = (GuiApplication)System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SapGui.ScriptingCtrl.1"));

    // How do I find the connection string that I use to connect to SAP?
    Connection = Application.OpenConnectionByConnectionString("XXXXXXXXX", false, true);
    Session = (GuiSession)Connection.Sessions.Item(0);

    Session.TestToolMode = 1;

    ((GuiTextField)Session.ActiveWindow.FindByName("RSYST-MANDT", "GuiTextField")).Text = "XXX";
    ((GuiTextField)Session.ActiveWindow.FindByName("RSYST-BNAME", "GuiTextField")).Text = "XXXXXXXX";
    ((GuiTextField)Session.ActiveWindow.FindByName("RSYST-BCODE", "GuiPasswordField")).Text = "XXXXXXXX";
    ((GuiTextField)Session.ActiveWindow.FindByName("RSYST-LANGU", "GuiTextField")).Text = "XX";            
}
```

I am getting an error when I run this code saying

> ...connection broken

How can I be sure of the correct connection string to use? Where can I find the connection string that I use to connect to SAP? Or is there a better way than using the `OpenConnectionByConnectionString()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this line of code:
Connection = Application.OpenConnectionByConnectionString("/H/IP Address/S/3200", false, true);

H: Host IP Address
S: Host Port Number. Default is 3200. Check yours.

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a part of the official documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/4f/992de4446d11d189700000e8322d00/content.htm) that describes the format of the route or connection string:

> **Definition**
>
> A route string describes the stations of a connection required between
>   two hosts. A route string has the syntax
>
> ```
> (/H/host/S/service/W/pass)*
> ```
>
> It consists of any number of substrings in the form
>   `/H/host/S/service/W/pass`.
>
> **Caution:** H, S, and W must be uppercase!
>
> **Structure**
>
> A route string contains a substring for each SAProuter and for the
>   target server. Each substring contains the information required by
>   SAProuter to set up a connection in the route: the host name, the port
>   name, and the password, if one was given.
>
> Syntax for substrings:
>
> - `/H/` indicates the host name. Note that the host name must be at least two characters long.
> - `/S/` is used for specifying the service (port); it is an optional entry, the default value is 3299
> - `/W/` indicates the password for the connection between the predecessor and successor on the route and is also optional (default
>     is “”, no password)

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is the name of the SAP area such as ERP, P56, or DFQ

```
Connection = Application.OpenConnectionByConnectionString("ERP", false, true);
```

Use that

Answer (score 0):

The "XXXXXXXXX" argument ("ConnectionString") is actually the *description* of the connection string that you can locate in the saplogon.ini file, which is at %AppData%\Roaming\SAP\Common