# Error handling in C# for SAP GUI Logon (GuiSession)

Tags: c#, user-interface, error-handling, sap-gui

I'm new to the SAP GUI API; but I manage to create a simple program (with C#) to automate data entry into SAP with reference from [how-do-i-automate-sap-gui-with-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130176/how-do-i-automate-sap-gui-with-c-sharp).

For the past few days I have tried to enhance the program by putting in error handling mechanism so that the program will able to show friendly message, if connection time or invalid logon info provided during logon. ***Catch all system/error messages from SAP** and display them in my program.*

However I have tried many ways to catch the error message via GuiSession.ErrorList and GuiSession.Error but it is not working - either return null or the program failed to compile.

Any help/advice on this will be appreciated.

Comment: I still struggling to catch the system/error messages prompted to the GUI. Any comment/input will be much appreciated.

Comment: I am currently reading the status bar (http://scn.sap.com/thread/744719) though still looking for other options