# SAP Front End Powershell script

Tags: powershell, sap-gui

Has anyone ever used powershell with SAP Front End? I am trying to build a script that creates a user in SAP GUI 7.30 and then assigns roles to the user. Does anyone ahve any reading material where I can learn this? I have looked all over the internet but can not find anywhere to start. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a good reason for not using the officially supported API (`BAPI_USER_CREATE1`, see http://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/func/bapi_user_create1.html and `BAPI_USER_ACTGROUPS_ASSIGN`, see http://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/func/bapi_user_actgroups_assign.html)?

Comment: Im afraid I don't quite know how that would be implemented in powershell.

Comment: You'd probably use the SAP .NET connector - does http://scn.sap.com/community/interoperability-microsoft-net/blog help?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options you could use.

1)  Stefan Schnell has created a **COM connector** for SAP GUI Scripting with Native PowerShell. You can start your research [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/03/16/use-sap-gui-scripting-with-native-powershell/) and [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/04/21/cco-com-connector-for-sap-netweaver-rfc-library-for-scripting-languages/). Disclaimer: I did not use it because Stefan’s site is currently down, and the component is thus inaccessible for download. And there are other options available.

2)  **Powershell + vbs**:  SAP GUI 7.30 has a WYSIWYG functionality that allows scripting out user actions into a .vbs file.

[image: Scripting in SAP GUI]

So you could create a user while script recording is on (this outputs a .vbs file with your scripted actions) and then launch this script from Powershell.

`c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\SAP\SAP GUI\Scripts\CreateUserAndAssignRole.vbs"`

If your SAP session is inactive, you’ll first need to launch the .exe file. Then your Powershell part would look like that:

```
  #-Set the path to the SAP GUI directory-------------------------------
    $SAPGUIPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\"

  #-Set the SAP system ID-----------------------------------------------
    $SID = "Your system ID (a description/name from SAP Logon)"

  #-Set the instance number of the SAP system---------------------------
    $InstanceNo = "00"

  #-Start the SAP GUI---------------------------------------------------
    $SAPGUI = $SAPGUIPath + "sapgui.exe"
    & $SAPGUI $SID $InstanceNo

  #-Call the logon script---------------------------------
    c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\SAP\SAP GUI\Scripts\login.vbs"
```

And the logon script:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").text = "yourMandant"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "yourUsername"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "yourPass"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").text = "yourLanguage"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

not much uglier than SAP, is it not?

3)  You could automate SAP GUI in **.NET**. A working example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130176/how-do-i-automate-sap-gui-with-c-sharp).

Personally I’ve done a lot of (3) in C# and although it provides many useful features (especially logging and error-handling), the c# code gets procedural and very cumbersome. Thus I migrate my solutions to (2).

Happy scripting!

Constantine.