# How do I attach current session to SAP GUI in C#

Tags: c#, sap-gui

I am trying to automate the SAP GUI. I have used the library SAPFEWSELib with which I am able to launch my the SAP GUI and connect. Now, I am created a desktop shortcut process (using a built in utility in SAP). So instead of launching and connecting every time I can directly go to the specific screen and automate the next steps from there. To achieve this, I would need to-

1. Trigger the desktop shortcut to launch SAP
2. Attach the current SAP session and perform the automation in C# using SAPFEWSELib library

I tried- `var session = SapGuiApp.ActiveSession;` but I get session as null. Is there any other way to attach the SAP session to SapGuiApp?

Note- `SapGuiApp` is a type of `GuiApplication` object which is accessible using SAPFEWSELib.

References-

1. [How do I automate SAP GUI with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130176/how-do-i-automate-sap-gui-with-c-sharp)
2. https://scn.sap.com/thread/159742

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to achieve that in C#:

```
SapROTWr.CSapROTWrapper sapROT = new SapROTWr.CSapROTWrapper();
object objSapGui = sapROT.GetROTEntry("SAPGUI");

object objEngine = objSapGui.GetType().InvokeMember("GetScriptingEngine", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objSapGui, null);

for (int x = 0; x < (objEngine as GuiApplication).Children.Count; x++)
{
    GuiConnection sapConnection = ((objEngine as GuiApplication).Children.ElementAt(x) as GuiConnection);
    string strDescr = (sapConnection.Description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in VBA, I guess you can do the same in C# with some edits, this function will give you some idea.
You will have to create the session from scratch

```
Function create_session() As Variant
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set sapApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set Connection = sapApplication.Children(0)
    Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    Set create_session = session
End Function
```

How to utilize this code snippet

```
mysession as object
set myesssion =  create_session()
sessionname = myession.id
```

do not forget to use the session killer

```
Function kill_session(session as object)
    Set SapGuiAuto = nothing
    Set sapApplication = nothing
    Set Connection = nothing
    Set session = nothing 
End Function
```

How to use it.

```
kill_session(mysession)
```

Comment: Works fine in VBA