# C# SAP automation using "SAPFEWSELib". How do I press a button from a drop down list?

Tags: c#, sap-gui

I use SAPFEWSELib to automate SAP. I have a problem to press a button from a drop down menu "as I guess :) ".

This code is auto generated by a SAP GUI script record. I need to reproduce this in C#:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_EXPORT"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

```
var ctrl = SapSession.ActiveWindow.FindById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell", false);
var shellToolbarContextButton = ((GuiShell)ctrl);
var btnToolbarContextButton = shellToolbarContextButton as GuiGridView;
btnToolbarContextButton?.PressToolbarContextButton("&MB_EXPORT");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to achieve the same results:

First, look at the code in the first answer as a reference to the static class utilized for my response here:[How do I automate SAP GUI with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130176/how-do-i-automate-sap-gui-with-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top).

Second, try the following line of code:

```
//Select Layout
        GuiGridView guiGridView = (GuiGridView) SAPActive.SapSession.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCCONTAINER/shellcont/shell");
        guiGridView.PressToolbarButton("&MB_VARIANT");
```

To make life easier and promote more productive coding, I created some basic methods within the SAPActive class that take in a string UI path and cast it to the desired object.
Here are some examples:

```
    /**
     * Takes in a string UI path Id and returns a GuiTextField linked to the
     * current session. Utilizes the SAPActive class.
     */
    public static GuiTextField TextFieldPath(string path)
    {
        GuiTextField rtnField = (GuiTextField)SAPActive.SapSession.FindById(path);
        return rtnField;
    }
    /**
     * Takes in a string UI path Id and returns a GuiMenu linked to the
     * current session. Utilizes the SAPActive class.
     */
    public static GuiMenu MenuPath(string path)
    {
        GuiMenu rtnField = (GuiMenu)SAPActive.SapSession.FindById(path);
        return rtnField;
    }
    /**
     * Takes in a string UI path Id and returns a GuiFrameWindow linked to the
     * current session. Utilizes the SAPActive class.
     */
    public static GuiFrameWindow FrameWindowPath(string path)
    {
        GuiFrameWindow rtnField = (GuiFrameWindow)SAPActive.SapSession.FindById(path);
        return rtnField;
    }
    /**
     * Takes in a string UI path Id and returns a GuiButton linked to the
     * current session. Utilizes the SAPActive class.
     */
    public static GuiButton ButtonPath(string path)
    {
        GuiButton rtnField = (GuiButton)SAPActive.SapSession.FindById(path);
        return rtnField;
    }
    /**
     * Takes in a string UI path Id and returns a GuiGridView linked to the
     * current session. Utilizes the SAPActive class.
     */
    public static GuiGridView GridViewPath(string path)
    {
        GuiGridView rtnField = (GuiGridView) SAPActive.SapSession.FindById(path);
        return rtnField;
    }
```

Now, the above code can be changed to the following:

```
GuiGridView guiGridView = SAPActive.GridViewPath("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCCONTAINER/shellcont/shell");
guiGridView.PressToolbarButton("&MB_VARIANT");
```

This is a great reference: https://help.sap.com/viewer/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/760.00/en-US/4af24c3281fb4d6a809e53238562d3b2.html