# C# Equivalent to Successful VBA Command capturing SAP GUI Client

Tags: c#, vba, sap-gui

I am attempting to control an open SAP GUI Client window through COM in a C# program.  The server version is S/4HANA, and the client is the SAP GUI 770 desktop client.

I have a VBA program where this works perfectly.  Subsequent code functions as expected:

```
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
```

When attempting what I believe is the equivalent in C#, it does not work.

```
object o = Marshal.GetActiveObject("SAPGUI");
```

This is the error message:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))'

I've tried every variant I can think of, and I've run the program as 32 and 64 bit with no change.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Have you looked at this previous post?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167169/capture-existing-sap-client-with-c-sharp

Comment: @TimWilliams -- oh yes; unfortunately no joy